# condition to dispatch either one option or the other

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to dispatch either the selectedMovie id or the selectedSerie id to redux. I am trying to make a condition. This is what I did now, I added a || operator but I don't quite know if that is possible.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isModalVisible) {
        if (Array.isArray(dt) && dt.length > 0) {
            dt?.forEach((el) =>
                dispatch(synt(language, el, SelectedMovie[0]?.id || 
SelectedSerie?.id))
            );
        }
    }
}, [dispatch, language, isModalVisible]);
```

Comment: It looks to me as if you might have your answer right there in your code. Unless zero is a valid movie ID, in which case your `||` should be a `??`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use of `||` is very much possible. When you use The logical OR `( || )` operator, if the first evaluation of the first operand is false, the second operand is evaluated.

```js
var a = (val) => console.log(val, "val")
x = {}
var e = 'e';
a(x?.ele || e);
a(x?.ele ? x?.ele : e);
```

**Solution 2: `??`**

[Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

`dispatch(syncToServer(language, el, SelectedMovie[0]?.id ?? SelectedSerie?.id))`

**Solution 3: `?` `:`**

Another way would be to use a `?` `:` operator.

```
dispatch(syncToServer(language, el, SelectedMovie[0]?.id ? SelectedMovie[0].id : SelectedSerie?.id))
```